# Placeholders for variables in UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want a `UIAlertView` to warn the user if there are no items matching his/her chosen search criteria. My initial idea was to use this code:

```
if (aOiCount == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No instances of %@",self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest message:@"Please select an activity or Cancel" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

The idea being to slip an actual activity name into the title, like in an `NSLog` string.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Compiler tells me `Expected ":"`

Is it possible to use a variable like this, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: `+[NSString stringWithFormat:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this line

```
@"No instances of %@",self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest
```

in one `NSString`

```
NSString *alertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of %@",self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest];
```

after that call your `UIAlertView` and then rearrange the word `delegate:nil` into `delegate:self`

```
if (aOiCount == 0)
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertStr message:@"Please select an activity or Cancel" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Your code works perfectly. Very grateful! Upvoted and accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is valid Objective C syntax:

```
initWithTitle:@"No instances of %@",self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest
```

You need to wrap it in an NSString, or a self-contained form.

Consider one of the many NSString methods, such as `stringWithFormat` or construct one in a different way. Either way, you should pass a complete string here.

Comment: Thanks! You're quite correct. I accepted the second answer because it included code, and therefore it got my immediate intention.